# How to structure encoder and decoder input sequences when building transformers model from scratch

Tags: transformer, pytorch, inference

I built a transformers model from scratch in PyTorch.  I trained it on a novel in the public domain.  My sequences are 30 tokens and the first encoder and decoder sequences, for example, are tokens 0-30 and 1-31, respectively.

In this way, my inputs do not have any padding tokens at all (I drop the last sequence that is incomplete).

For inference, I encode an input sentence with padding for the encoder input, whereas the decoder input is just a BOS token with padding.

My question is, is this the proper way to set up the sequences?  Seems that the way I have it set up is problematic -  the model never sees any padding tokens in the inputs, which leads to problems when it encounters them during inference.

I suppose one alternative would be to assign a sentence (with padding as necessary) to each sequence.  But then what would the decoder input contain?  Also in general this is much more data processing than the current approach.

For reference, the reproducible code is on this SO thread (although the question there is a slightly different one):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77984828/generate-prediction-sequence-with-transformers-model-built-from-scratch